# Having trouble with a lab assignment (Using lists and integers)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Our lab assignment this week is to make a simple version of blackjack running in Python 3. I've got most of the assignment finished but I'm having trouble with the part where I need to determine points for each card. Here's a mockup of my code for the segment I'm stuck on.

```
def score(playerhand, comhand):
    playerscore = 0
    comscore = 0
    for i in playerhand:
        if playerhand == str('A'):
            playerscore += int(11)
        elif playerhand == str('J'):
            playerscore += int(10)
        elif playerhand == str('Q'):
            playerscore += int(10)
        elif playerhand == str('K'):
            playerscore += int(10)
        else:
            playerscore += int(playerhand) #This is where it breaks
```

Playerhand is a list that will contain 2 or 3 random strings between 1-10, or A, J, Q, or K (These are aces and face cards). As it stands, I can't think of a simple way to convert the value of playerhand to an integer without making a bunch of elif statements to convert every string to its integer counterpart. I can't use playerhand[x] since the for loop is going to loop through every value in playerhand anyway. I've been at this for a while, if anyone can throw some help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure if stackoverflow is the right place for this question. But you should probably just use a dictionary mapping to map the values of each card to an integer, that way you can do something like `player_score += cards[playerhand]`

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my last resort if I couldn't find a way to make this work. I supposed I'll get started on that while I wait for anymore answers.

Comment: Probably a typo, though your line after `elif playerhand == str('Q'):` is missing a `)` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are misusing `playerhand` inside the loop.  Given the loop expression `for i in playerhand`, `i` represents a single element of the list.  So inside the loop, you should be using `i` instead of `playerhand` to refer to the current element.  `playerhand` still refers to the entire list.

With that change, the solution you have of calling `int()` may work fine.  A better overall solution would be using a dictionary as already suggested in a comment, but given that this is a lab assignment, it may be intended for you to use only certain data structures.

Another solution would be to have a list that contains all the possible strings, and a second list of the same length that contains the corresponding scores.  Find a given string in the first list, then find the element of the second list at the same position, and that is the score.

Comment: Looks like that was my error, I knew it'd end up being something dumb and simple.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem within the given text of code I see straight away is using `playerhand` rather than `i`; for `i` represents each value of `playerhand` in sequential order from the beginning of the list.

Everything else seems as though it'd work fine, nevertheless using a dictionary may be a good way to go as well. Though since you're doing this as a lab assignment, that may be more than what your teacher is looking for.